# Unable to understand "Different databases" section in stack document

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I' reading stack document from https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/

In the section of Different databases, it says that

> Databases in stack are layered. For example, the database listing we just gave is called a local database. That is layered on top of a snapshot database, which contains the libraries and executables specified in the snapshot itself. Finally, GHC itself ships with a number of libraries and executables, which forms the global database. To get a quick idea of this, we can look at the output of the **stack exec -- ghc-pkg** list command in our helloworld project:

```
/home/michael/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.2/lib/ghc-7.10.2/package.conf.d
   Cabal-1.22.4.0
   array-0.5.1.0
   base-4.8.1.0
   bin-package-db-0.0.0.0
   binary-0.7.5.0
   bytestring-0.10.6.0
   containers-0.5.6.2
   deepseq-1.4.1.1
   directory-1.2.2.0
   filepath-1.4.0.0
   ghc-7.10.2
   ghc-prim-0.4.0.0
   haskeline-0.7.2.1
   hoopl-3.10.0.2
   hpc-0.6.0.2
   integer-gmp-1.0.0.0
   pretty-1.1.2.0
   process-1.2.3.0
   rts-1.0
   template-haskell-2.10.0.0
   terminfo-0.4.0.1
   time-1.5.0.1
   transformers-0.4.2.0
   unix-2.7.1.0
   xhtml-3000.2.1
/home/michael/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/nightly-2015-08-26/7.10.2/pkgdb
   stm-2.4.4
/home/michael/helloworld/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/nightly-2015-08-26/7.10.2/pkgdb
   acme-missiles-0.3
   helloworld-0.1.0.0
```

I did the same experiment on windows, but the results are different:

1. Create a new project by `stack new helloworld`
2. Edit `helloworld/src/Lib.hs` as following

   ```hs
     module Lib
         ( someFunc
         ) where

     import Acme.Missiles

     someFunc :: IO ()
     someFunc = launchMissiles
   ```
3. Edit `helloworld/package.yaml` as following

   ```yaml
   dependencies:
   - base >= 4.7 && < 5
   - text
   - filepath
   - containers
   - acme-missiles
   ```
4. Since `acme-missiles` be not in LTS, so I add a `extra-deps:` in `helloworld/stack.yaml`

   ```yaml
   extra-deps:
   - acme-missiles-0.3 # not in the LTS
   ```
5. `stack build` and success, log as following

   ```
   E:\work-category-theory\helloworld>stack build
   Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 8.6, and using 8.8.3, this may fail
   Stack has not been tested with Cabal versions above 2.4, but version 3.0.1.0 was found, this may fail
   acme-missiles> configure
   acme-missiles> Configuring acme-missiles-0.3...
   acme-missiles> build
   acme-missiles> Preprocessing library for acme-missiles-0.3..
   acme-missiles> Building library for acme-missiles-0.3..
   acme-missiles> [1 of 2] Compiling Acme.Missiles
   acme-missiles> [2 of 2] Compiling Acme.Missiles.STM
   acme-missiles> copy/register
   acme-missiles> Installing library in C:\sr\snapshots\c1955c78\lib\x86_64-windows-ghc-8.8.3\acme-missiles-0.3-5Q3zlWTjrQa
   Fyz88eRyQT2
   acme-missiles> Registering library for acme-missiles-0.3..
   Building all executables for `helloworld' once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified executables will
    be rebuilt.
   helloworld   > configure (lib + exe)
   Configuring helloworld-0.1.0.0...
   helloworld   > build (lib + exe)
   Preprocessing library for helloworld-0.1.0.0..
   Building library for helloworld-0.1.0.0..
   [1 of 2] Compiling Lib
   [2 of 2] Compiling Paths_helloworld
   Preprocessing executable 'helloworld-exe' for helloworld-0.1.0.0..
   Building executable 'helloworld-exe' for helloworld-0.1.0.0..
   [1 of 2] Compiling Main
   [2 of 2] Compiling Paths_helloworld
   Linking .stack-work\dist\29cc6475\build\helloworld-exe\helloworld-exe.exe ...
   helloworld   > copy/register
   Installing library in E:\work-category-theory\helloworld\.stack-work\install\5056a8ea\lib\x86_64-windows-ghc-8.8.3\hello
   world-0.1.0.0-BBUUJBmDe2RHSTnItHQtB0
   Installing executable helloworld-exe in E:\work-category-theory\helloworld\.stack-work\install\5056a8ea\bin
   Registering library for helloworld-0.1.0.0..
   Completed 2 action(s).
   ```
6. Now call `stack exec -- ghc-pkg list`

   ```
   E:\work-category-theory\helloworld>stack exec -- ghc-pkg list
   Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 8.6, and using 8.8.3, this may fail
   Stack has not been tested with Cabal versions above 2.4, but version 3.0.1.0 was found, this may fail
   C:\Users\Chansey\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.8.3\lib\package.conf.d
       Cabal-3.0.1.0
       Win32-2.6.1.0
       array-0.5.4.0
       base-4.13.0.0
       binary-0.8.7.0
       bytestring-0.10.10.0
       containers-0.6.2.1
       deepseq-1.4.4.0
       directory-1.3.6.0
       filepath-1.4.2.1
       (ghc-8.8.3)
       ghc-boot-8.8.3
       ghc-boot-th-8.8.3
       ghc-compact-0.1.0.0
       ghc-heap-8.8.3
       ghc-prim-0.5.3
       ghci-8.8.3
       haskeline-0.7.5.0
       hpc-0.6.0.3
       integer-gmp-1.0.2.0
       libiserv-8.8.3
       mtl-2.2.2
       parsec-3.1.14.0
       pretty-1.1.3.6
       process-1.6.8.0
       rts-1.0
       stm-2.5.0.0
       template-haskell-2.15.0.0
       text-1.2.4.0
       time-1.9.3
       transformers-0.5.6.2
       xhtml-3000.2.2.1

   C:\sr\snapshots\c1955c78\pkgdb
       acme-missiles-0.3

   E:\work-category-theory\helloworld\.stack-work\install\5056a8ea\pkgdb
       helloworld-0.1.0.0
   ```

You can see that my outputs are different from the document.

The question is:

Why `acme-missiles-0.3` is in `C:/sr/snapshots/` rather than `/helloworld/.stack-work`? (Note that, in windows, `C:/sr/` be equivalent to `~/.stack`)

Also, in the FAQ of the document from https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/, it mentioned that

> **Where is stack installed and will it interfere with ghc (etc) I already have installed?**
>
> Stack itself is installed in normal system locations based on the mechanism you used (see the Install and upgrade page). **Stack installs the Stackage libraries in ~/.stack and any project libraries or extra dependencies in a .stack-work directory within each project's directory.** None of this should affect any existing Haskell tools at all.

`acme-missiles-0.3` is extra dependencies, why in my experiment, it is in `~/.stack` rather than `.stack-work` directory within project's directory?

Thanks.

Comment: If you think that stack's documentation is out of date, you can bring it up on their issue tracker.

Comment: @sjakobi I can't make sure it is a document out of date. In fact, the stack issue tracker let me ask question here...(sorry, I am not very familiar with Haskell ecosystem)

Comment: You're referring to https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/5271, right?

Comment: @sjakobi No, they are different issues. Here the acme-missiles-0.3 refer to an actual remote dependency , not a folder which I unzipped in the project.

Comment: @chansey It appears recent versions of Stack are able to cache extra-deps as long as they are pulled from an immutable source. See, for instance, the comments at [issue #3922](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3922), or [the build overview page](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/build_overview/) ("Immutable package: a package which comes from Hackage [, or etc.] [...] [For] immutable tasks: check the precompiled cache for an identical package installation"). That might explain why, in your output, `acme-missiles` shows up in a snapshot database identified only by a hash.